# How to get WinInet's proxy settings quickly (without network dependency)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, proxy, winhttp

How can I quickly retrieve Internet Explorer's proxy settings from C++?

The windows function `WinHTTPGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser()` gives me exactly what I want.

The problem with `WinHTTPGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser()` is it is running unacceptably slowly on some of my user's systems (they are running Windows 7). For these users, the function takes multiple seconds to complete. It seems to have a networking dependency, since if they unplug the network cable the function returns fast (and with the same result).

So how can I get the system proxy settings without this slow network dependency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Poking the registry directly isn't supported. The proper mechanism to get the IE's proxy settings is to call `InternetQueryOptionList` with the `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` structure and the appropriate flags for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve these details from the registry. The registry keys are mentioned here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961/EN-US